# Cannot configure MFA even after acquiring Azure AD Premium P1 license

Tags: licensing, multi-factor-authentication

I am trying to configure two-factor authentication for a specific set of users from a particular location.

For that, I recently purchased Azure AD Premium P1 license and I'm the global admin of my azure account.

But the issue is, even after doing all these, I am unable to configure conditional policy and it is showing as disabled for me.

I am not understanding what setting is really needed here. Is there any other way to configure MFA to users other than conditional access?

Or do I need any specific permission to make it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***With Azure AD Premium P1 license, you can configure conditional access like below:***

Please try assigning **`Security Administrator role`** and note that it may take a few hours to reflect.

To configure MFA for specific set of users from particular location, create one user group and one named location based on your requirements like below:

[image]

**Create a new conditional policy like below:**

[image]

**In conditions select location and choose named location you created like below:**

[image]

**In Grant, select required MFA and create like below:**

[image]

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

[Enable Azure AD Multi-Factor Authentication - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/tutorial-enable-azure-mfa)

[Azure Conditional Access can't Include or Exclude users (spiceworks.com)](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2354107-azure-conditional-access-can-t-include-or-exclude-users)

Comment: As you said, after granting the Security Administrator role, it activated late. The next day I am able to configure CA. Thanks for the info